# How to automatically create a callback for automatically created sliders and graphs

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have an app that is for plotting line charts of different parameters  with the following functionality:

[image]
I have been able to make it such that for each parameter selected, the line graph will be plotted along with sliders for varying the date and parameters.

The sliders are to help the user to interact with the plot to see data at different values and time.

The date slider is  not a problem.

The problem is the parameter sliders, they are able to be created but my problem is how do I connect them to the parameter's line graph as they are automatically created and the parameters vary from one data to another.

Is there a way of creating automatic callbacks because that is the only way I know to tie a component to the data.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen any examples of dynamically creating callbacks, however I think you should be able leverage some of the features from [multi-page apps](https://dash.plotly.com/urls#multi-page-apps-without-pages) to achieve the effect.

What you will need to do is:

1. Suppress callback exceptions in your app by adding `suppress_callback_exceptions=True` to your `Dash()` constructor.
2. Decide on a ID / naming convention for each your parameter sliders
3. Write the callbacks taking the IDs you chose as Inputs and the line graph as Output
4. Dynamically add in the slider components as required giving them the IDs you chose in step 2

As default Dash will not let you write a callback that references ID that do not exist in your layout and will error on start. However, you can override this behaviour with the `suppress_callback_exceptions` flag.

By suppressing the exceptions, you can now write a callback that references components that do not exist in your layout when the app starts, but they will still get triggered by components with the given IDs if they are then dynamically added to the application at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.
I will try and use that

Comment: I have been able to solve this using pattern-macthing callbacks.
I will post an example of the solution during the weekend.